# Can we give the test data, without labelling them?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I came across this snippet in the Tensorflow documentation, [MNIST For ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).

```
eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

Now, I want to feed my own test images, without labelling them and would like the model to predict the labels, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but it would not be deep learning instead it would be clustering. ( Ex: [K means Clustering](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/kmeans.py) )

Basic idea is like the following:

1. Create two placeholders for input and centroids
2. Decide a distance metric
3. Create graph
4. feed **only** dataset to run the graph